# show a form from click point

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to find some kind of component or widget to make it appear when I click on the main window. The trick is to make it appear expanding downwards from the click(upper left corner) to the lower right corner.
I'm using Qt 4.7.4(32 bits)

thanks already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive a class from QWidget (or QMainWindow) and reimplement [mousePressEvent](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) (or mouseReleaseEvent) in there you can get the [position of the click](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html#pos) (from the `QMouseEvent *event` parameter), create the widget you want to show, [move](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#pos-prop) it to the position and finally show it.